# How to run JUnit Plugin Tests from Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit, eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP Java application, and I've created some tests for it. When I run them within the IDE using `JUnit Plug-in Test` it runs fine, but when I run `mvn test` or `mvn clean install` it throws a `NullPointerException` when trying to get a hold of an instance of a plugin class. I can replicate this behaviour within the IDE by running the test as a normal `JUnit Test`, implying that that's what Maven is doing.

Is there a plug-in I'm missing from my pom hierarchy, that enables the running the tests as JUnit Plugin Tests?

Comment: See https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html#executing-plug-in-unit-tests-with-tycho